# How to install torch when I have pytorch 1.10.1

Tags: pytorch, conda, torch

I am working on Compute Canada.

I am trying to install torch >= 1.7.1 because when my code has import torch but it fails even though I installed pytorch already in my conda environment and it is version 1.10.1.

I tried `pip install torch >= 1.7.1`, and this response

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

Comment: This version of pytorch doesn't exist.

Comment: I typed it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Answering to:

> I am trying to install torch >= 1.17

There is no pytorch version `>= 1.17`. The latest version is `1.10.2`.

> my code has import torch but it fails even though I installed pytorch already in my conda environment

This is the issue that you should address instead. There is similar issues like this here on SO, but they usually are caused by the fact that you are running your code with a python interpreter that is different from the conda env that you have installed `torch` to.